# How to add product to customer`s cart by admin restApi

Tags: cart, addtocart

I know only admin token, customer Id, and product Id. How can I add this product to customer`s cart using RestApi?

Comment: Refer this https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items/

Comment: But the problem is that i can`t get customer token. I want to add item to cart only by admin token.